# Fastest way to generate ~10^9 poisson random numbers in python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random, poisson

I would like to find the fastest way to generate ~10^9 poisson random numbers in python/numpy—for instance, say I have a mean Poisson parameter (calculated elsewhere) of shape (1000, 2000), and I need 500 independent samples. This is a bottleneck in my code, taking several minutes to complete. I have tried three methods, but am looking for something faster:

```
import numpy as np

# example parameters
nsamples = 500
nmeas = 2000
ninputs = 1000
lambdax = np.ones([ninputs, nmeas]) * 20

# numpy, one big array
sample0 = np.random.poisson(lam=lambdax, size=(nsamples, ninputs, nmeas))

# numpy, current version where other code happens in the loop
sample1 = np.zeros([nsamples, ninputs, nmeas])
for i in range(nsamples):
    sample1[i, :, :] = np.random.poisson(lam=lambdax)

# scipy
from scipy.stats import poisson
sample2 = poisson.rvs(lambdax, size=(nsamples, ninputs, nmeas))
```

Results:

```
sample0: 1 m 16 s
sample1: 1 m 20 s
sample2: 1 m 50 s
```

Not shown here, I am also parallelizing the independent samples via `multiprocessing`, but the calculations are still pretty expensive for such large parameters. Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the range of means for the Poisson samples?  If they are very small, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614458/performance-for-drawing-numbers-from-poisson-distribution-with-low-mean . If you will form a sum of the Poisson variables, just take a single Poisson variable with the sum of their means.

Comment: @PeterO. the means can vary quite a bit, from close to 0 to values in the thousands. Unfortunately, for subsequent steps in the analysis I need the full noised sample of `lambdax` for each of the `nsamples`

Comment: Will `lambdax` (in your example) contain the same value in all its entries?  If not, your example will likely not show typical performance.

Comment: @PeterO. fair point, no, `lambdax` will have different values in general. Each of the `ninputs` rows will be fairly similar to each other, but across the `nmeas` columns the values will vary quite a bit

Comment: If I do something arbitrary like `lambdax[i, j] = 10*np.sin(j/10) + 20 + i`, the times are 55 s, 59 s, and 1 m 31 s, respectively. I'm guessing there's some speedup under the hood when the Poisson mean is >> 20 or so.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in your shoes and here are my suggestions:

- For large mean values, poisson works similar to uniform. check out [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158355/how-large-does-a-poisson-distributions-mean-need-to-be-to-use-normal-distributi) (and probably more if you search) .
- ~1m runtime seems reasonable to generate such a large number of random numbers. I don't think you can top `sample0` method by much via just coding. Now depending on what you want to do with random numbers,

  - if your issue is rerunning program multiple times, try saving `sample0` into a file and reloading it in the next runs.
  - if not, I suggest creating lower number of randoms and reuse them. A lot of those random numbers in `sample0` will be repeated in your sample, depending on your mean value. You might want to create smaller sample size and randomly choose from them. for example I would chose a random number from `sample0` and reuse it for e.g. 100 times (since that number would appear in `sample0` over 100 times anyways).

If you provide more information on what you intend to do with random numbers, we might be able to help more. Otherwise, coding-wise I am not sure if you can do much further.

Comment: I'm simulating gamma-ray detectors, so I'm Poisson noising a model of `nmeas` measurements to generate realistic statistical noise. I'm doing this `nsamples` times for `ninputs` realizations of noise in the input parameters. The issue comes when on top of that, I simulate dozens of different input parameter sets. Come to think of it, I can probably just do one Poisson noise per input noise, i.e., `nsamples = 1 if ninputs > 1`...

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. If I understand it correctly, your poisson mean is a constant 20? in that case, if you create a 10^9 samples from it, there will be a lot of repetitions (maybe an array of 1k-10k would even suffice). You can simply generate a small number of samples and use `np.rand.choice` to randomly chose from it to add to your array as noise. I would even suggest to bundle your gamma-ray input array indices into groups and add same noise to each group, if your array is significantly larger size than your poisson mean value.

Comment: It's not a constant 20, no. As discussed above it can range from ~0 to values in the thousands, so pre-generating a small number of samples won't work. I'm also working in mean counts, not discrete counts, so I can't generate integer counts either. I can see how your `np.rand.choice` solution would work in the (constant) integer case, though. My realization above is that, in the broader picture, I probably just need to run fewer sample, especially by only performing one Poisson noise for each input noise.

Comment: Yes. correct me if I am wrong, isn't the sample0 code you provided with constant mean? Nonetheless, if per input, mean is constant, you can do one smaller sample per mean vs. around 1M that I can see in code now. Even with mean of 1000, a sample of 1M would be too much(of course it depends on your accuracy goals too). I am not sure if I understand mean counts vs. discrete counts. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The `sample0` was just something I quickly put together. As Peter O pointed out, that was not really representative. Hence the other `lambdax[i, j]` formula deep in the comments above, with a variable mean. And I was conflating two ideas talking about mean vs discrete counts, sorry—ignore that! I will think a bit more about this small subset idea. It certainly is intriguing.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarifying. Hopefully it gets resolved.